# How to prove that the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ can be expressed as the intersection of countably many open sets?

Tags: measure-theory

And also it cannot be expressed as the countable union of closed sets. Why is that?

Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, use the fact that $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, and that points are closed.

For the second question, try using the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 1):

For every $q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1], U_q=[0,1]-\{q\}$ is open in $[0,1]$, consider $\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}U_q$.

Comment: here the closed subsets are the points, I am usin $\sigma$-additivity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity